# how to export firefox 'about:config' into plain text file?

Tags: firefox, export

so, how can I **export the WHOLE 'about:config'** from firefox into plain text file. Screenshot would be good enough although text file is preferred.

My favorite firefox extention sceengrab cannot handle it.

Please note that I am on Mac and I cannot find 'prefs.js' file.

Comment: I found it here `/Users/radek/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/h2it03j8.default/prefs.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want your preferences on another computer you can just export the [prefs.js](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=225420&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) file. I'll keep looking in case there is a specific reason you need a text file, although technically a .js is a text file of sorts. [This](http://techjournal.318.com/mass-deployments/mass-deploying-firefox-preferences-for-mac-os-x/) should clue you in as to where prefs.js is on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you click "Show All",
you will see the full list of settings.

Since this is just an HTML table,
you use right click -> "Select All"
and then copy and paste them into a spreadsheet or text editor.
This is essentially the same as exporting it as a tab-separate value (TSV) file.

Answer (score 0):

I have create an autoit script to automatic export the configuration content and compare with python. Check the article and scripts from my blog http://www.shangerxin.com/?p=262